# Tensoring a skew field does not introduce zero divisors

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

Let $D$ be a skew field with centre $K$ and maximal subfield $E$. Let $F$ be a finite extension of $K$ disjoint to $E$, that is, $F\cap E=K$. Is it true that the tensor product $D\otimes_K F$ has no zero divisors?

This is false in the complementary case: indeed, if $F\supseteq E$ then the tensor product will be a matrix ring since $E$ is a splitting field, and hence it will contain zero divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that although it is common in the literature to treat linear disjunction in a very casual way, in itself $F\cap E=K$ is not meaningful, as $F$ and $E$ are not both subfields of a bigger field. Or if they are, it should be explicit (lots of authors don't do it, and they are wrong because it *can* actually depend on the choices of embedding and not just on the isomorphism classes).

But in any case, no, what you are asking is not true: $D$ can have linearly disjoint splitting fields. For instance, if $D=(a,b)_K$ is a quaternion algebra, then you may take $E=K(\sqrt{a})$ and $F=K(\sqrt{b})$, which will be linearly disjoint if you take $a$ and $b$ to have different non-trivial square classes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out: in the question, the fields were tacitly understood to lie inside a common (algebraically closed) supfield.